# Java Kafka Object serilizer and deserializer

Tags: java, json, serialization, apache-kafka, deserialization

I am doing kafka producers and consumers. there are three ways to do Serialization and de-serialization.

1, custom object -> byte[] -> object ([example](https://blog.knoldus.com/2017/01/30/kafka-sending-object-as-a-message/))

2, custom object -> String -> object (I tried. working)

3, custom object -> JsonNode -> object ([example](https://gist.github.com/sdpatil/f803ff60dd0e9c5f8664fcd5fbb60242))

Which one is better? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try benchmarking but I would imagine all three are about the same.

1. **Object -> byte[]**: In this case three things are happening.

   1. Object is converted into a tree of Json objects.
   2. Tree is converted to a string.
   3. String is converted to bytes.
2. **Object -> String**: In this case the same three things are happening.

   1. I assume you are using the object mapper, which builds a tree of Json objects internally and converts the tree to a string.
   2. I also assume you are using the StringSerializer which lets kafka convert the string to bytes.
3. **Object -> JsonNode**: Again same three things are happening.

   1. The object mapper in producing a tree of Json objects.
   2. The JsonSerializer converts the tree to a string and the string to bytes.

If you're interested in maximizing performance you might want to avoid using json as a serialization mechanism and explore [protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/).
A kafka protobuf example is [here](https://github.com/zuowang/kafka-protobuf). Some numbers comparing protobuf performance vs json serialization are [here](https://dzone.com/articles/is-protobuf-5x-faster-than-json).